# I'm coding a discord bot, but when I'm using the ping command its shows me 0 ms. what should i do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a ping command but when I'm using it the ping is 0.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "this is the ping command",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const msg = message.channel.send("**Pinging...**").then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 0 }));

        const embed = new MessageEmbed().setColor("#42d242").setDescription(`**:hourglass_flowing_sand:  ${message.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}**`);

        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Comment: `message.createdTimestamp -  message.createdTimestamp` is like calculating `1-1`, it will always return 0 because you are deducting the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're using `message.createdTimestamp -  message.createdTimestamp`. If we replace those with a random number to represent the time, we get `573 - 573`. Obviously that equals zero. You're subtracting the number from itself. Try something like

```
var ping = await msg.channel.send("Fetching ping...");

    const pingEmb = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#42d242")
    .setDescription(`:hourglass_flowing_sand: Heartbeat is ${client.ws.ping}ms,\nMessage Roundtrip took ${ping.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms.`);

    return ping.edit("", {
        embed: pingEmb
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is always returning 0 is that you are deducting [`message.createdTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createdTimestamp) from itself, which will always result in 0 because it is the same number.

---

The solution is to create a [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and use [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to get the [`UNIX Timestamp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and deduct it from [`message.createdTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createdTimestamp).

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "this is the ping command",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const msg = message.channel.send("**Pinging...**").then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 0 }));

        const embed = new MessageEmbed().setColor("#42d242").setDescription(`**:hourglass_flowing_sand:  ${new Date().getTime() - message.createdTimestamp}**`);

        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Comment: Why use `new Date().getTime()` when they can just use the `createdTimestamp` value of `msg`? In me experience using `new Date().getTime()` isn't as accurate as `msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp`, but ymmv

Comment: @APartOfMe If you use `msg.createdTimestamp` you're measuring the time between two messages, not the current time. This method may result in the ping being higher.